# reading value-pair from .properties file in parent directory

Tags: servlets, bundle, properties-file

I have servlet that's under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat_8.0.9\webapps\myApp
```

I have 3 .properties file under folder properties:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat_8.0.9\properties
```

Once I deploy this on linux it will be also under `webapss/properties` directory...

Right now, on my windows machine, I ahve following code taht doesn't work:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\tomcat_8.0.9\\webapps\\properties");

URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ldap = ResourceBundle.getBundle("js.ldap.properties", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
smtp = ResourceBundle.getBundle("js.smtp", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
db   = ResourceBundle.getBundle("js.db", Locale.getDefault(), loader);

String adminName = ldap.getString("ldap.provider.admin.user");  
System.out.println("adminName name: "+ adminName);
```

It's throwing Can't find bundle for base name js.ldap, locale en_US

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *I have 3 .properties file under folder properties:*: what's their name. Paste the output of `dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat_8.0.9\properties`. Why don't you bundle the properties in the same classpath as your app? Why do you put classes and properties files under this directory, which is supposed to contain war files to deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working :)

```
FileInputStream dbfis   = new FileInputStream("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\tomcat_8.0.9\\webapps\\properties\\js.db.properties");  

dbProp.load(dbfis);
String userName = dbProp.getProperty("db.username");                        
Strinpassword   = dbProp.getProperty("db.password");              
String port     = dbProp.getProperty("db.port");
String server   = dbProp.getProperty("db.host");
String dbName   = dbProp.getProperty("db.name");
```

Thank you people for helping

Comment: OK.  Don't forget my advice in the other question you asked, about not hardcoding the tomcat home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

> I have 3 .properties file under folder properties:
>
> ```
>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat_8.0.9\properties
> ```

But your code is looking in

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat_8.0.9\webapps\properties
```